# Why is encrypted DNS treated as a application-level protocol rather than an OS-level one?

Tags: dns, encryption

I was doing some reading recently about how DNS is one of the few protocols that runs by default in clear text, and there were discussions about how various browsers and apps are incorporating encrypted DNS. So you, as the user, basically have to take a specific action in each app (e.g. Brave browser) in order to use encrypted DNS.

**Question: Why is it up to the individual app developers to include support for encrypted DNS?** Seems like this would be an operating system kinda thing.

Like in my case, my computers default to using Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) and Google (8.8.8.8) for DNS. I guess I figured that when an app (browser or otherwise) wants to resolve a hostname, it would ask the OS API -- which would then attempt encrypted DNS against 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 and, failing that, would fall back to clear text. In other words, I had always assumed that DNS lookup was a OS-specific chore, not something that had to be implemented by each and every app. If that is indeed the case, what's the rationale behind that design decision?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it up to the individual app developers to include support for encrypted DNS? Seems like this would be an operating system kinda thing.

I think this downplays the aspects of flexibility and efficiency.

Everything on the internet is distributed, there are a lot of moving parts. It's likely easier for an application developer to provide support for a given standard or method of communication, rather than relying on OS developers.

For instance, let's say Fancy Encryption v2 has just been released. Which is easier? One application developer including it in their own program, or waiting for a minimum of 3 general OSes (Windows, Mac and Linux) to slow-roll it into their products (assuming they even agree it's a worthwhile standard to include)?

And this really isn't hypothetical. Technically, there are currently two general methods of DNS encryption:

- [DNS over TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_TLS) ([IETF RFC7858](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7858)) (2016)
- [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) ([IETF RFC8484](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8484)) (2018)

That's also setting aside issues of backwards compatibility. Not all DNS servers even use encryption at this point. So which standard(s) should be used? What happens if you want to choose one (or neither) but your OS decides differently? Locking the ability to communicate with a third-pary up into the OS means that whomever is producing the OS (by default) has a lot more control over that communication.

> I guess I figured that when an app (browser or otherwise) wants to resolve a hostname, it would ask the OS API -- which would then attempt encrypted DNS against 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 and, failing that, would fall back to clear text.

Why potentially increase the workload of the OS or a DNS server by making multiple queries for the same site? The initial DNS resolvers you're contacting either use encryption or they don't. This is generally known ahead of time, since computers initially contact a fixed pool of DNS servers to resolve queries. Arguably, using this kind of "fallback" method seems wasteful from a communications efficiency standpoint.

Comment: But isn't this the state of affairs with *current* DNS? It's baked into the OS. When an app developer wants to resolve a hostname, he'll just call a ResolveDNSHostname() function and let the OS do the work, as opposed to creating app-specific DNS configuration popups for the user to fill out. To your second point, I don't see the 'try and fail' bit would have to be run for each query; It would only have to be run once at system boot to see if DNS servers support encryption or not. Further, isn't this how IPv6 was gradually integrated? Integration was an OS-level thing, not up to app devs.

Answer (score -1):

So let's go back to the basics. Not exactly the stone age, but just the bit after. You have a lot of connection queries performed and none of them are secure. Well to be fair, encryption is not yet applied as a standard. Do you perform the queries? Well yes and no. "YES" because you click some buttons, "NO" because the app does it. What am I talking about? Mosaic, the thing that served as the basis of IE.

Fast forward a bit and we got to the "next level": tabbed browsing in Netscape Navigator. For those born "late', this served as a milestone (not only in the MS antitrust case but also in Firefox and the Mozilla Foundation being born). By now we all got acquainted with the risks of networking (and I don't mean social networking) so we can discuss anything from webpage password encryption to wifi security algorithms.

But let's slide between. Encryption got introduced sometime between that, right? We use it everywhere from local networks to anything and everything in some form or another. Sure, not as advanced as something after 2000, but still a start. Not feeling up to date? No problem, we can fast forward to things after 2000.

By now we all know the "current" encryption scheme we got used to by using SSL was not secure. We had all types of malware and insertion schemes got more complex, from compiler programs to apps being downloaded after accessing QR codes.

Still, let's not divert from the question and focus on security: so we got SSL, we moved to TLS, so what? Tell me, how did you access connections? Did you select TLS? Anywhere? Or was the browser configured to do so? You might even have local apps that initiated (or listened to connections) that required a certain algorithm or method. Did you select it? Maybe, but it was either you or the app, not the OS.

Enough blah-blah. Let's move to the answer. While the OS can supply the backbone (that is libraries, algorithms, settings, support aso) what each app uses as a connection is a design choice. And you might say "what happens if the current settings, algorithms, libraries and standards are hax0rd?". Well the answer was hidden under the boring intro of this answer. The beauty of new OSes is that they are dynamic and modular. It doesn't even matter if at some point the OS is behind the technology. Someone can just invent/develop a technology, supply a library and a new app can use it.

This means that each encryption can not only be OS-version independent (meaning it won't matter what version your OS is), but also OS-agnostic (meaning it won't mean what OS it is). The simplest way (although some die-hard devs will kill me for mixing up those terms so loosely) would be to say that a technology (yes - including executables, libraries, scripts aso)can be cross-platform.

But let's cross over from the coding front to to what you want to know: DNS. DNS is more networking than coding. Well "yes and no". So, you I told you about a bit of history, about the design approaches and advantages, but how do they finalize into an end-product for networks?
Just remember that networks have a very specific way of approaching things: ports. While to use "HTTP" and "HTTPS" are a something clear, the simplest way to explain that to a network is using ports. That in turn is based on standards.

While we can go over the design cycles of a standard and an application, let's wrap it up and say, that imagine a centralized way, such as an OS. And let's not talk about DNS necessarily, but any other request. Isn't it easier to just hack a single point of entry and gain access to secure info before it reaches the destination, instead of having an easily manageable way of being constantly updated? (a simple example: Vault 9 approach to breaking whatsapp and telegram encryption by hacking the entry/exit points where it is NOT encrypted, just before encryption starts/after it ends, same for TOR, where most hacks happen at TOR nodes)

TLDR, an OS doesn't know what a DNS is, what a DNS request is, what a HTTP request is aso. It's just a payload. You need dedicated apps that do that. While we can discuss default DNS like 1-1 and 8-8, again, we know about Google and Cloudflare. The OS doesn't. And hijacking a hostname using a hosts file is easy. The OS has a different job, not to route Netflix to you or to tell you the IP of a WoW server. What the OS does, is it can provide you with the tools needed to get the info you need. And if it doesn't, you can use external libraries. To put it simply, the concept of DNS (and any other such requests) can be easier seen as having any simple console environment that can serve as an OS and do its job. Everything has to be transparent and OS-independent.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I enjoyed learning this history behind this stuff. I'm pretty sure the OS knows what DNS is though. It's set on boot via DHCP and the user can override it if he wants to. When an arbitrary app wants to resolve a hostname, it just makes a call to a known system-level API, doesn't it? In other words, I don't think Terminal, Brave,  and any other apps that require hostname resolution are writing their own name resolution logic (e.g. lookup system DNS IP, connect to it, craft a DNS query and send it, wait for response, etc.). They're just making an API call, no?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "API call". Even if it you think of it as a REST, SOAP or even a trivial C function call, in the end, it's still a query done to a DNS server. The OS might provide the backbone, but that's it. Can you really say that Windows or Linux can connect you to an onion server without TOR? Which is accessed how? Via the OS or via an app? We can go on the chicken-or-egg discussion and ask whether TOR uses the OS or the OS uses of what the app offers, but I think I made my point :) The discussion is of course a lot deeper, but I'm trying to restrict it to the basics.